# Widget does not work - JQuery-mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, widget

I have the following collapsible widget in JQuery Mobile:

[image]

When I update the page(press F5), this widget does not work anymore as you can see in the picture:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h1>
                    What belongs to you but others use it more than you do? <br>(Click
                    for the answer)
                </h1>
                <p>Your name!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try 'refreshing' the collapsible element:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function () {
        $("div[data-role='collapsible']").collapsible();
});
```

Hope helps!